# SQLALCHEMY_BINDS - Could not locate a bind configured on SQL expression or this Session

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i got this error message while executing stored procedure **SP_ACC_MUTATION** in SQL Server using Flask and SQLAlchemy.
here's sneakpeek of my codes, this SQLAlchemy Statement must be connect to 'db1' :

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'db1': 'mssql+pyodbc://sqlserver:sqlserver@127.0.0.1:1433/ACCOUNT_DB?Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server&Encrypt=No&TrustServerCertificate=Yes',
    'db2': 'postgresql+psycopg://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/API_AUTH_USER'
    }

query = text("EXEC SP_ACC_MUTATION :account, :page")
records = db.session.execute(query, {'account': account, 'page': page})

result = [{'ROWS': row.row_no, 
           'ACCOUNT': row.account, 
           'ACCOUNT_NAME': row.account_name, 
           'AMOUNT': Tools.get_idr_format(row.amount), 
           'TOTAL_PAGES': row.TotalPage
          } for row in records]

return jsonify(result)
```

how do i resolved this ?